# Обмен столбца. Язык С

Tags: c

Обмен столбца

В заданном двумерном массиве целых чисел найти индекс столбца максимального
элемента двумерного массива – пусть это column. Требуется поменять местами первый
столбец со столбцом с индексом column и вывести получившийся двумерный массив.

Input
Со стандартного устройства ввода в первой строке вводятся 2 целых числа M и N –
соответственно количество строк и столбцов двумерного массива: 1<=M<=100,
1<=N<=100. В следующих M строках вводятся ровно по N элементов – значения
элементов двумерного массива. Все значения в массиве от -100 до 100.

Output
Требуется вывести получившийся после обмена двумерный массив A. После каждого
элемента матрицы требуется выводить пробел.

Sample Input

```
3 4
1 2 3 3
4 5 6 3
7 8 9 3
```

Sample Output

```
3 2 1 3
6 5 4 3
9 8 7 3
```

Примечание
Если максимальный элемент встречается в двумерном массиве более одного раза, то
требуется выбрать первый при обходе матрицы по строкам от нулевой до последней.

Мой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int n, m, i, j, b[100][100],a[100][100],max,v,g;
    scanf("%d%d", &n, &m);
    for (i = 0; i <n ; i++)
        for (j = 0; j <m; j++)
            scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);
    v = 0;
    g = 0;
    max = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        max = max + b[i][0];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a[i][0] = b[i][0];
    for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            g = g + b[i][j];
        }
        if (g > max) {
            max = g;
            v = j;
        }
        g = 0;
    }
    j = v;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        b[i][0] =b[i][j];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        b[i][v] = a[i][0];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
            printf("%d ", b[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Набирает 50 из 100, что не так?

Comment: нашел пример, когда ваш код не работает. в прямоугольнике из 3 строчек и 4 столбцов. 1 столбец: 1 3 1 2, 2: 1 3 3 3, 3: 2 3 4 4. столбец с максимальным элементом - 3, а программа ставит на первое место 2 столбец. подсказывать не буду, скажу только, что нахождение столбца делается за один обход (два вложенных for), а обмен столбцами делается одним for. подсчитайте, сколько for у вас.

Comment: предположу, что вы неверно поняли первое предложение в условии задачи.

Comment: А у вас же получается 4 строки и 3 столбца

Comment: извиняюсь, ошибся в слове. 1 строка: 1 3 1 2, 2: 1 3 3 3, 3: 2 3 4 4. итого 3 строки и 4 столбца.

Comment: Аааа, прочитал ещё раз и понял, что сумму искать то не надо))

Comment: А что сейчас не так?)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
 int n, m, i, j, b[100][100],max,v,g;
 scanf("%d%d", &n, &m);
 for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
   scanf("%d", &b[i][j]);
 v = 0;
 max = b[0][0];
 for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
   if (max < b[i][j])
   {
    max = b[i][j];
    v = j;
   }
  }
 }
 for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
  g = b[i][0];
  b[i][0] =b[i][v];
  b[i][v] = g;
 }
 for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
   printf("%d ", b[i][j]);
  printf("\n");
 }
 return 0;
}

Comment: не смотрел пока еще, но у вас точно обход по строкам (как требует условие)? тогда почему for(j<m) for(i<n)? может в другой последовательности надо? или перепутали при чтении их местами? желательно называть переменные как в постановке задачи, чтобы не путаться.

Comment: Я беру столбец и проверяю по строкам, если вы про этот фрагмент                                   
`for (j = 0; j < m; j++) {
 for (i = 0; i < n; i++)`

Comment: написал в ответе, прогнал ваш код (из комментария)

Answer (score 0):

Решил ответить в ответе, а не в комментарии. Правильный код писать не буду, только свои мысли, как можно решить правильно.
Итак, первую проблему локализовали: нужно считать максимальный элемент, а не сумму.
Проблема вторая, до сих пор не решенная: нужно делать обход матрицы [по строкам](https://bstudy.net/719474/informatika/obhod_elementov_matritsy).

Рассмотрим контрпример, который демонстрирует, что обход по столбцам:

```
3 4
1 3 1 4
1 3 3 3
2 3 4 4
```

Получаем ответ:

```
1 3 1 4
3 3 1 3
4 3 2 4
```

Смотрим примечание к задаче:

> Примечание Если максимальный элемент встречается в двумерном массиве более одного раза, то требуется выбрать первый при обходе матрицы по строкам от нулевой до последней.

Т.е. алгоритм должен был выбрать последний столбец, а не предпоследний. Поэтому тесты все еще выдают ошибку.